# Conditionals applied to verbs

Tags: conditionals

> I would eat that

translates to

> 私はそれを食べるだろう

My question here is, every conditional + verb has the structure verb + だろう? Or is it more complex than this?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but I can already say _it's more complex than this_.

Comment: The Japanese doesn't actually have a conditional construction.  It just has the speculative modal marker だろう.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of conditional — verb + だろう — is a very explicit way to mark a conditional. Conditionals in Japanese are generally not explicitly stated as such, but are rather interpreted based on the surrounding/ongoing context.

I think the sentence you quoted above, in more natural Japanese might be something like, 「私だったら、(それを)食べる。」, where the conditional is given context by the 「私だったら」clause ("If it were me").

I am not one hundred percent confident about this next statement, but I feel that using 「verb + だろう」 as a conditional (in the sense of a "would" clause in English) to talk about your own actions may sound a bit unnatural in Japanese.